# What do _._1 and _++_ mean in Scala (two separate operations)?

Tags: scala

My interpretation of `_._1` is:

`_` = wildcard parameter
`_1` = first parameter in method parameter list
But when used together with `.` what does it signify?

This is how its used :

```
.toList.sortWith(_._1 < _._1)
```

For this statement:

```
_++_
```

I'm lost. Is it concatenation two wildcard parameters somehow? 
This is how its used:

```
.reduce(_++_)
```

I would be particularly interested if they above code could be made more verbose and remove any implicits, just so I can understand it better?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`_._1` calls the method `_1` on the wildcard parameter `_`, which gets the first element of a tuple. Thus, `sortWith(_._1 < _._1)` sorts the list of tuple by their first element.

`_++_` calls the method `++` on the first wildcard parameter with the second parameter as an argument. `++` does concatenation for sequences. Thus `.reduce(_++_)` concatenates a list of sequences together. Usually you can use `flatten` for that.

Answer (score 13):

`_1` is a method name. Specifically tuples have a method named `_1`, which returns the first element of the tuple. So `_._1 < _._1` means "call the _1 method on both arguments and check whether the first is less than the second".

And yes, `_++_` concatenates both arguments (assuming the first argument has a `++` method that performs concatenation).

Answer (score 5):

```
.reduce(_++_)
```

is really just:

```
.reduce{ (acc, n) => acc ++ n }
```